# Softlayer VLAN association and protection options

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We have a Softlayer account with multiple VLANs configured in one datacenter. When launching an instance we can specify which vlan it should use for its frontend and backend interfaces, but if we don't seemingly they will be chosen randomly.

First question:
 - can we set the default frontend/backend VLANs for a datacenter that will be used when there is nothing provided explicitly in the request?

Second question:
 - can we protect a VLAN so that nobody but a specific user could provision devices in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that the answer for your two questions is no. By default softlayer does not provide those features, but you can build your own Portal for your customer using the [Softlayer API](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/overview) and add that functionality to control those stuff.